# Calling Azure DevOps REST API using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rest, azure-devops

I am currently trying to make a GET call to Azure DevOps Rest API using JavaScript however, I am having a hard time doing so. How will I be able to accomplish this?

This is what I have for the uri.

```
uri: https://dev.azure.com/<team project>/_apis/projects?api-version=2019-12-01
```

Comment: You should put some code out here to show what you've tried and what went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples/blob/master/JavascriptWebAppSample/index.html). You have there an example.

But if you want to use pure vanila here you have sth:

```js
var request = new XMLHttpRequest()

request.open('GET', 'https://dev.azure.com/thecodemanual/_apis/projects?api-version=5.1', true)
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8;');
request.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa('Basic' + ":" + 'YOUR_PAT_TOKEN'));

request.onload = function() {
  // Begin accessing JSON data here

  var data = JSON.parse(this.response)

  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    console.log(data)
  } else {
    console.log('error')
  }
}

request.send()
```